# Rue and cats/dogs

Tags: herbs

Is it true that rue (Ruta graveolens) is a cat and dog repellent?

I read the question "[Planting to deter cats](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9416/planting-to-deter-cats)", but rue is not mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I never found it bothered my own cats, who were perfectly happy to lay underneath or right next to it in the shade, although I too have heard it's supposed to be repellent to them. Equally, the only (visiting) dog that was in the garden periodically didn't seem to be troubled by it either. What it might bother is you or any children you have; brushing against it sufficient to bruise the leaves in sunlight can cause a severe and painful rash with blistering, see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_graveolens